# Curl does not work from PHP on Nginx and localhost

Tags: php, ssl, curl, nginx, wpn-xm

When I send the Curl request from local PHP script to the local server via SSL (running nginx 1.9.4 on Windows via WPN-XM) then the browser is "waiting" until it gets the 504 error. The PHP-fpm is probably dead, because the web server does not proccess any other request.

When I send the same request to the production server it works correctly.

When I send the Curl request from command line, then it works.

When I open the final resource in web browser then it works.

I have spent 4 hours googling and reading Stac Owerflow, but did not find any other situation like I have.

Thanks!

---

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://webserver.local/resource");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); // just on local
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // just on local
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Status 504](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261536/http-status-504)

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is not a duplicate of all the 504 questions. I do not need more time for my script, it is a simple API resource called just from one request in the time.

Comment: Did you read what a 504 error is though? It's a likely problem with the upstream connection timing out and/or the server itself. You should at least give more details about it, and show the code you are actually using to make the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script will not work with the default configuration of WPN-XM v0.8.6,
because there is only one php-cgi process listening in the background, but your example needs (at least) two of them. php-cgi is already used by the script doing the curl request and so Nginx is unable to forward it to php-cgi. That means you will first run into a blank page with a loading indicator and then hit the connection timeout.

The underlying problem is that php-cgi does not automatically spawn new processes (when needed). The issue is discussed over here: https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/issues/323

There are two solutions:

- use a tool for spawning the servers, like

  - https://github.com/WPN-XM/php-cgi-spawner/releases
  - or `spawn-fcgi` from the http://www.lighttpd.net/ project to start `php-cgi`
- or start more php-cgi processes and configure an nginx load balancing/upstream pool

**Update 03-2016:**

> To solve the situation for the WPN-XM stack i've added `php-cgi-spawn\spawn.exe` by default. This allows to spawn multiple PHP
>   daemons. The spawner will be used in PHP version below v7.1.
>
> PHP v7.1 will have this solution implemented and provide better FCGI
>   MultiPlexing out-of-the-box.

---

**spawn-fcgi**

The first solution is a modification to `start.bat`. You would simply put spawn-fcgi in front of php-cgi, like so:

`spawn-fcgi -f "%_dir%\php-cgi.exe" -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9100 -C 6 -F 4 -P "%_dir%..\temp\php.pid"`

I have no clue where this tool is hiding, maybe there is a standalone download somewhere, but its possibly part of the lighttpd distribution for windows.
I think i will compile it from source and make it available for WPN-XM.

**php upstream pool**

The second solution needs two small steps to get a PHP worker pool up and running.

- The first step is to alter the `start.bat` file to start multiple php-cgi daemons, each listening at a different port. We add some more php-cgi starts:

  ```
  :start-php
      echo Starting PHP FastCGI...

      set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0
      set PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4

      %HIDECONSOLE% %~dp0bin\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9100 -c %~dp0bin\php\php.ini
      %HIDECONSOLE% %~dp0bin\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9101 -c %~dp0bin\php\php.ini
      %HIDECONSOLE% %~dp0bin\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9102 -c %~dp0bin\php\php.ini
      %HIDECONSOLE% %~dp0bin\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9103 -c %~dp0bin\php\php.ini
  ```
- The next step is to modify `server\bin\nginx\conf\nginx.conf` and activate the `php_pool`, instead of using the single upstream.

  Simply look for `fastcgi_pass   php;` and change it to `fastcgi_pass   php_pool;`.

This change will activate the following upstream pool, which is already defined:

```
upstream php_pool {
    server 127.0.0.1:9100 weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
    server 127.0.0.1:9101 weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
    server 127.0.0.1:9102 weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
    server 127.0.0.1:9103 weight=1 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
}
```

That's all.

Run `start.bat` and then your "curl post to localhost" example should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens, your pack is great and the "php upstream pool" way helped me. However I need to start the server with the start.bat now, do I need to do anything else to be able to run this edited "start.bat" from Control Panel?

Comment: I'm glad you like the stack. Unfortunately the SCP does not support the start of multiple PHP processes. You will have to work with the batch file for a while, until the next version comes out. (I will extend the SCP configuration dialog and add a dropdown to select the number of CGI processes to start. And a pool of 2 processes will be the new default value, for batch and SCP, so that nobody runs into this issue again.)