# Understanding HTTP 504 Result from Spray Web Service

Tags: scala, http, spray

Given:

`client <-- HTTP --> spray web service <-- HTTP --> other web service`

The `client` receives the following HTTP status code and entity body when hitting the `spray web service`:

`504 Gateway Timeout - Empty`

Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494758/409976), my understanding is that the `spray web service` is not receiving a timely response from the `other web service`, and thus sending an `HTTP 504` to the `client`.

Assuming that's reasonable, per https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/StatusCode.scala#L158, I'm guessing that one of these `server` [config values](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-can/configuration) is responsible for the `504` in the `spray web service`'s HTTP response to the `client`.

What config or implicit would cause the `spray web service` to reply with a 504 to the `client`?

Comment: This problem may occur when http requests to `other web service` timed out. This may be caused by bad network or ssl configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the default Spray timeouts and perhaps you will need to increase them. If this is the case, there are 2 values you will have to configure to increase the timeouts.

1. idle-timeout: Time you can have an idle connection to your server before it is disconnected (default 60s).
2. request-timeout: Time a request from your client (from your server to another) can be idle before it timesout (default 20s).

The first value must be always higher than the second, as the idle-timeout will make pointless the connections from your request client.

So just overwrite your configuration in your `application.conf` like this:

```
spray.can {
    server {
        idle-timeout = 120 s
        request-timeout = 20 s
    }
}
```

Comment: From my [testing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/c40gsTAcYmc), it's also necessary to increase the `sendReceive` time-out.

Comment: I suppose that you will also need to update your client http properties with something like: `spray.can { client { idle-timeout = 120 s    request-timeout = 20 s } }`