# Ajax HTTP Error 504.0 - Gateway Timeout

Tags: php, ajax, http

I'm having the **HTTP Error 504.0** error in my application.

**Architecture.**

I mounted a REST API using Slim on the server X (on the web). When I make any `request` to this API from my computer the API returns me the data almost instantly. That is, it works correctly.

However, when I try to interact with the API through a `PHP` application via `AJAX` that I also mounted, being hosted on another server from another domain the error happens.

[image]

Comment: Just seems to be a cross-origin problem. Allow in the server to get requests from another domain. You can set a php header for this `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: origin`. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers#9866124

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS with php headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)

Comment: Thanks, but is not CORS :(

Comment: Ok, you're right. Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261536/http-status-504

Comment: Yeah Marcos, but not. Cause my request "localhost->API" its really fast. 169ms / Size: 428B  :(

Comment: Have you got a firewall or something that can block requests? If yes you can try to allow all connections from the app IP to the API IP. I feel that I can't help you better :(

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I dont know cause i just buy the host service, its not "mine". But i can make localhost requests. So, not looks its firewal.

Comment: This is a really hard question :'(

Comment: It doesn't matter. Can be the firewall. If the firewall blocks an IP, that iP will be unable to access to server, but if you change the IP or the machine you will get access with no problem. You can try to talk to your host provider if they have installed firewall or another security methods that can block access from another server, or where you can see iptables and so on. However, I don't tell you that's the reason of your problem, but you need to try something to see what's wrong on your system.