# cannot integrate Jenkins with TFS : EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: jenkins, tfs, devops

I am trying to integrate Jenkins (2.6) with TFS 2013. I have installed the Jenkins plugin `Team Foundation Server Plug-in (5.121.0)`. However, when I try to configure the `TFS` plug-in in Jenkins to contact the `TFS` Team Project Collections by mentioning THE URL of the default collection of `TFS` (http://localserver:8080/tfs/mcdonalds), I get an error  :

```
com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.EndpointNotFoundException: The SOAP endpoint localserver:8080/tfs/mcdonalds/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 504
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First double confirm if you could connect your TFS server collection through web portal.

[HTTP Status 504](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261536/http-status-504) usually related to proxy or gateway issue.

TFS plugin was attempting to use the HTTP proxy to connect to the TFS server. Double check your proxy settings. You could try to update the no proxy host configuration under **Jenkins > Plugin Manager > Advanced** to match the wildcard domain that our TFS server resided on, and try the connection again.